# How to add multiple values into a page, and then to controller in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this scenario to implement in ASP.Net MVC.

In my view, I would like to have a dropdown with a button , where on click of Button, will add selected values into probably a Div table. There will be a separate 'Save' button which will call the ActionResult POST method to save these values to the database.

Here, I could probably use AJAX to add values into the Div (However I am not sure how I can pass the values here to the controller once user clicks on the 'Save' button).

I was also thinking I could probably do a postback and add the values into a Session value (Probably an ASP.Net Web Form technique?) and call the ActionResult POST Method once the user clicks a separate 'Save' button.

Hence, in an ASP.Net MVC framework, what would be the best way to implement this scenario?

Thanks.

Comment: The view is bind to the view, u can put the value to Div table same time put to hidden field which also bind to one of your model's property. Or the best is Ajax post back, pass in Json value.

Comment: Go and have a read of this: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Answer (score 0):

You can put all you hml into a @html form and then on save buton click you can either post that for to server or you can write a click event of that form by making ajax call.In ajax call you can send form data by form.serialize method.